# Improvement of iteration thru data frames

Tags: python, pandas, nested-loops

Trying to find some insides in two data frames,know that loops are not solution in pandas and using two sheets with 15k rows each. How can I improve the speed on the code that follows? Its not possible to use merge because after matching the condition row from err need to be removed in order to don't be matched again. It takes 140 min with 16k rows.

```
import pandas as pd

scr = pd.DataFrame({
    'Product':['10101.A', '10101.A', '10101.A', '10147.A', '10147.A', '10147.A', '10147.A','10147.A'],
    'Source Handling Unit':['7000000051481339', '7000000051481342', '7000000051722237','7000000051530150','7000000051530152', '7000000051530157', '7000000051546193', '7000000051761150'],
    'Available Qty BUoM':[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
    'Confirmation Date':['10-5-2022', '10-5-2022', '9-5-2022', '6-5-2022', '6-5-2022', '6-5-2022', '6-5-2022', '11-5-2022']
    })

err = pd.DataFrame({
    'Posting Date':['4-5-2022','6-5-2022','11-5-2022','11-5-2022','11-5-2022','11-5-2022','11-5-2022','11-5-2022','11-5-2022','13-5-2022','15-5-2022','16-5-2022','25-5-2022'],
    'Product':['10101.A', '10147.A', '10101.A', '10101.A', '10101.A', '10101.A', '10101.A', '10101.A', '10101.A', '10101.A', '10101.A', '10101.A', '10147.A'],
    'Reason':['L400', 'CCIV', 'UPLD', 'UPLD', 'UPLD', 'UPLD', 'UPLD', 'UPLD', 'UPLD', 'UPLD', 'UPLD', 'L400', 'L400'],
    'Activity Area':['A970', 'D300', 'A990', 'A990', 'A990', 'A990', 'A990', 'A990','A990', 'A990', 'A990','A970','A970'],
    'Difference Quantity':[1, 5, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, 1, 1]
})

#Creating filter for scr
filt_scr_col = ['Product', 'Source Handling Unit', 'Available Qty BUoM', 'Confirmation Date']
#Applying filter
scr = scr[filt_scr_col]

#Creating filter for err
filt_post_col = ['Posting Date', 'Product', 'Reason', 'Activity Area', 'Difference Quantity']

#Applying filter
err = err[filt_post_col] 

#Replace empty characters with underscore 
scr.columns = scr.columns.str.replace(' ', '_')
err.columns = err.columns.str.replace(' ', '_')

#Creating filter to extract A450 rows from postings
filt = err['Activity_Area'] == 'A450'

#Assign A450 rows to new dataframe a450
a450 = err.loc[filt]

#.groupby 'Posting_Date', 'Product','Reason' but when I pass an argument as_index = False doent aggregate Products returns relevant object
#.query gets Difference_Quantity > 0 this evaluates and refers to exact row
a450 = (
    a450.groupby(['Posting_Date', 'Product','Reason'], as_index = False, sort = False).sum()
    .query('Difference_Quantity > 0')
    )

#Creating filter to remove all < 0
filt = err['Difference_Quantity'] > 0

#Applying filter to dataframe
err = err.loc[filt]

#Removing column 'Activity_Area' from err don't need it and columns will match when appent with a450
err = err.drop(columns='Activity_Area')

#Concat err and a450
err = pd.concat([err, a450], ignore_index= True)

scr['Confirmation_Date'] = pd.to_datetime(scr['Confirmation_Date'], format = "%d-%m-%Y")  
err['Posting_Date'] = pd.to_datetime(err['Posting_Date'], format = "%d-%m-%Y")

scr = scr.sort_values(by='Product', ascending=True)
err = err.sort_values(by='Posting_Date', ascending=True)

scr['Reason'] = None
match = []
for i, row in scr.iterrows():
    for e, erow in err.iterrows():
        if (row['Product'] == erow['Product']) & (erow['Posting_Date'] >= row['Confirmation_Date']) & (erow['Difference_Quantity'] - row['Available_Qty_BUoM'] >= 0):
            row['Reason'] = err['Reason'][e]
            err['Difference_Quantity'][e]-= row['Available_Qty_BUoM']
            row_to_dict = row.to_dict()
            match.append(row_to_dict)
            break
report = pd.DataFrame(match)  
report = report[['Product', 'Source_Handling_Unit', 'Available_Qty_BUoM', 'Confirmation_Date', 'Reason']]

#Pandas think that report['Source_Handling_Unit'] has floats and love to round them
report = report.astype({'Source_Handling_Unit': str})
report
```

Comment: Indeed loops are not the right tool. Please explain what you are trying to do

Comment: Hello @gtomer added comments, hope that it gets a bit clear

Comment: Your code has many errors when running it. It is hard to help this way. What is the deisred output?

Comment: Please excuse me, was on rush and pasted wrong code all works fine now with desired_output included

Comment: How do you go from `report` to `desired_ouput`?

Answer (score 2):

Setup:

```
scr = pd.DataFrame({'id' : ['10101.A', '10101.A', '10101.A'],'date' : ['10-5-2022', '10-5-2022', '9-5-2022'], 'qty': [1, 1, 1]})
err = pd.DataFrame({'id' : ['10101.A', '10101.A', '10101.A'], 'date' : ['4-5-2022', '13-5-2022', '16-5-2022'],'qty': [1, 1, 1], 'r':['a', 'b', 'c']})
scr['date'] = pd.to_datetime(scr['date'], format = "%d-%m-%Y")  
err['date'] = pd.to_datetime(err['date'], format = "%d-%m-%Y")
```

Doing:

```
df = scr.merge(err, on='id', suffixes=[None, '_er']).drop_duplicates()
report = df[df['date_er'].ge(df['date']) & df['qty_er'].sub(df['qty']).ge(0)]
print(report[['id', 'date', 'qty', 'r']])
```

Output:

```
        id       date  qty  r
1  10101.A 2022-05-10    1  b
2  10101.A 2022-05-10    1  c
7  10101.A 2022-05-09    1  b
8  10101.A 2022-05-09    1  c
```

---

Another approach would be a sql-like one, this may be more efficient on a large dataset:

```
from pandasql import sqldf
pysqldf = lambda q: sqldf(q, globals())

query = '''
    select distinct scr.id, scr.date, scr.qty, r
    from scr
    join err
    on scr.id == err.id
    and err.date >= scr.date
    and err.qty - scr.qty >= 0
'''

df = pysqldf(query)
df.date = pd.to_datetime(df.date)
print(df)

...

        id       date  qty  r
0  10101.A 2022-05-10    1  b
1  10101.A 2022-05-10    1  c
2  10101.A 2022-05-09    1  b
3  10101.A 2022-05-09    1  c
```

Comment: Cool, I can definitely learn some stuff from this code!   I'm looking at `er['qty'] -= r['qty']` in the original code.. I think it does .. nothing, right? So it doesn't matter for the translation.

Comment: Thanks BeRT2me, will deep dive into you solution and test it tomorrow, if you have time for comments will be very much appreciated and can you please show me how to report.groupby(['id', 'date', 'qty', 'r']) without aggregate and will match the desired output, @creanion er['qty'] -= r['qty'] was suppose to remove er['qt'] after iteration, so one next iteration to don't be included as value.

Comment: I tried the original method on two 15k row dataframes, and quickly ran out of memory, but the SQL method worked fine without issues.

Comment: @creanion pinging you, just because I thought you might be interested in the changes~

Comment: BeRT2me Thanks!  and @B02T I think it doesn't do anything - because writing to the row you get from iteration does not write back into the dataframe itself.

Comment: @BeRT2me thanks, result should be  10101.A 2022-05-09    1  c, 10101.A 2022-05-10    1  b, that is like those items when thru the err and we take the out of err, ones conditions are met we have to remove err['qty'], if we count scr we have 3 "units", from err we have 2 units that match same criteria, if we sort 'date' 9-5-2022 goes thru 13-5-2022 and we have to remove the qty of 13-5-2022, then next 10-5-2022 goes thru 16-5-2022 we remove the quantity of 16-5-2022 and we done , remove the quantity if there are other units they can pass the check and be excluded from err as well

Comment: Updated OP with my progress so far, the result is correct.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you right, the bellow code is quick without loops:

```
import pandas as pd
scr = pd.DataFrame({'id' : ['1a', '1a', '1a', '1b'], 'date' : ['10-5-2022', '10-5-2022', '9-5-2022', '11-5-2022'], 'qty': [1, 1, 2, 2]})
err = pd.DataFrame({'id' : ['1a', '1a', '1a', '2s'], 'date' : ['4-5-2022', '13-5-2022', '16-5-2022', '12-3-2022'], 'qty': [1, 1, 3, 5], 'r':['a', 'b', 'c', 'a']})
scr['date'] = pd.to_datetime(scr['date'], format = "%d-%m-%Y")  
err['date'] = pd.to_datetime(err['date'], format = "%d-%m-%Y")
# merging the two dataframes
arr = scr.merge(err, on='id', how = 'left')
# filtering
arr = arr[(arr['date_x']<=arr['date_y']) & (arr['qty_x'] == arr['qty_y'])]
arr
```

Comment: thanks for the feedback, It doesn't provide the desired output,  have added new data to the OP

Comment: If we first filter scr on (err['date'] < scr['date']) & (err['id'] == scr['id']), and after that merge it